# How do I add tables in Medium?

Tags: medium

I'd like to add a simple table (as in Google Docs or other word processor), with links on some of the text. Medium.com does not seem to support this.

I have found some

- [Yabwe is a "Medium editor"](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor), but apparently is a clone of Medium,  rather than a tool to be used with Medium.com
- [This article](https://medium.com/@mesirii/5-tips-for-embedding-tables-in-your-medium-posts-8722f3fc5bf5) gives five approaches, including screenshot, plaintext tables, embedding Airtable, but these seem quite clumsy and do not support richtext with hyperlinks.
- [Sheetsu has a solution](https://sheetsu.com/table-for-medium), but this is for embedding sheets, not word-processor-tables. Richtext and hyperlinks not supported.